# $M:\mathbb{R}^{5\times5} T: M\to M$ denote the operator $T (A)=\frac12(A-A^T)$, find kernel,range,nullity,rank,real eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, transpose

My question is
$M:\mathbb{R}^{5\times 5} T:M \to M$ denote the operator $$T (A)=\frac12(A-A^T)$$ where superscript $T$ is the matrix transpose. How can I find kernel,range,nullity,rank,reel eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Firstly,
I checked T preserves sums and multiplication by scalars than I found this is linear map.
$T(A+B)=T(A)+T(B) T(c.A)=c.T(A)$.
If this matrix was $2\times 2$ I draw matrix $A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}$
Then I could calculate $$T(A)=\frac12(A-A^T)$$ then could find kernel,range,nullity,rank.

But this matrix is $$(5\times 5)$$. So I can't draw like $2\times 2$ matrix and couldnt calculate
$$T (A)=\frac12(A-A^T)$$
Can you suggest another way for me to calculate these values(kernel,range,nullity,rank,real eigenvalues and eigenvectors)?

Comment: **Hint :** What is $T(A)$ if $A$ is a symmetric matrix ? and if $A$ is an antisymmetric matrix ?

Comment: A matrix A is symmetric if and only if A =A^T.  But how this can help me?

Comment: Can you answer my questions ?

Comment: A is symmetric if and only if A =A^T then T(A) is zero vector.

Comment: ... and, maybe this can help you find the kernel ?...

Comment: Unfortunatelly couldnt understand.kernel is identity?